# How to use git with Symfony 2?

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

I installed Symfony 2 with Composer (following the 'master' guides), and it created this .git/config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard
    pushurl = git@github.com:symfony/symfony-standard.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "composer"]
    url = git://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/composer/*
```

I don't want to interfere with what Composer did here since I don't know how it works, and I want to be able to update the vendors in the future.

So how do I add my own repository for 'myapp' and commit/push to it? I usually do 'git remote add origin ...' and only work with that, but now there are two repositories in the file, plus the one I need to add.

**UPDATE**

I installed Symfony2 with this command:

```
$ php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition myapp
```

This created myapp/ and installed Symfony2 + dependencies. But now composer.json does not look like it's ready to use for my project, it looks like my project is Symfony2 itself (I think):

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "dev-master",
    "twig/extensions": "dev-master",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.0.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
    },
    "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

**Master Guides**

- http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/installation.html (for the first step, which is downloading symfony, I used the composer command, as shown here: http://symfony.com/download)
- http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html (this one seems to be outdated, since it says we have to do 'git init', but the git repo is already created by composer)

Comment: You normally do this in your composer.js file. That file specifies what your code needs. Commit composer.js with your code.

Comment: @hakre I'm not trying to add dependencies to my code, I'm trying to version my code.

Comment: Please drop a link to those master guides, probably I then better get what you're concerened about because normally you just use git ;) (as you do)

Comment: You can delete the `.git` folder in the root directory and do `git init` again.

Comment: @m2mdas Are you sure? Won't that ruin the composer settings? What if I need to update symfony or vendors? Why is .git dir even there? Why did composer add that, if I only need the libraries, not their entire history? What should I do with composer.json? My project is not symfony itself, symfony should be just another dependency

Comment: AFIK `composer.phar create-project` command  clones the project, reads the dependency from the `composer.json` file, clones them and puts them in the vendor directory and generates `autoload.php` accordingly AND the deletes the `.git` folder in root directory. So if you follow the git workflow doc it won't be much problem. As you have seen in the doc, vendor folder is listed in `.gitignore` file. So if you create a new bare repository after deleting the `.git` folder git wont watch on vendor folder. You can just issue `php composer.phar update` for updating libraries. It is portable also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can safely remove the *.git* folder and run *git init* to initialise your own repo just like @m2mdas suggests.

Composer is not doing anything special here. It just clones the [symfony-standard](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard) project and then installs its dependencies.

Composer clones the repository but it doesn't need the *.git* folder to work. In fact I don't think it should be cloning projects by default. Might be they'll fix it in future versions.

Composer uses *composer.json* file and you should manage all your dependencies with this one file. You can safely edit it to add or remove packages.

Then, to update packages just run:

```
php composer.phar update
```

All the packages removed from composer.json will be removed, those you added will be installed. Existing packages will be updated to the latest version.

You should store the generated composer.lock file in your repo to be sure you'll always get the same versions of dependencies when you run:

```
php composer.phar install
```

composer.lock is updated when you first run install and with every update command.

Comment: If you create your repo for symfony project , how do you restore it in an other directory?